# Detecting a missed call in lollipop - CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android

I've a routine that's worked in all versions of android to detect missed calls, but now even if a call is rejected it's still showing as missed.

I'm using

```
localContentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER}, "type=3 AND new=1 AND DATE>"+lastClearAllDate, null, "date DESC");
```

`3` is the type "missed" and new=1 ensured they've not already been viewed.

Does anyone know whats changed in lollipop that means that even rejected calls are added to the missed type?

Comment: I know I can get if it's missed with the notification service but even in Lollipop google don't populate the "people" section to be able to pick up on who the missed call is from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a bug in android 5.0 as it was fixed in later versions